# Intent.putExtra() dont update its value

Tags: java, android, widget

I have 3 buttons in my home screen widget. After click i want to launch my activity with some parameter (it depends which button was clicked).
The problem is that value is always 0 (it should be 0, 1 or 2, depends on which button was clicked).
My code looks like this:

```java
for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
   RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.simple_app_widget); 

   for(int z=0;z<widget_buttons.length;z++) {
      int id = Integer.valueOf(widget_buttons[z]);
      if(z<accounts_array.length) {
          String[] data_array = accounts_array[z].split("\\,");

          Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
          Log.e(APP_TAG, "## ACCOUNT_ID: "+ data_array[0]);
          intent.putExtra("accountID", data_array[0]);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          views.setOnClickPendingIntent(id, pendingIntent);
          views.setTextViewText(id, data_array[1]);
       } else {
          views.setViewVisibility(id,View.INVISIBLE); //hide button
       }
    }

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

First loop is for update every widget, second is for registering click event on 3 buttons.

This is how I retrive data in MainActivity.java

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Log.e(APP_TAG, getExtra("accountID"));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String accountParam = "";
    if (extras != null) {
        Log.e(APP_TAG, "AccountID in MainActivity: "+extras.getInt("accountID"));
        accountParam = "?accountID="+extras.getInt("accountID"); //<---
    }

    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"+accountParam);
}
```

Can you please tell why every button after click gives 0 from extras.getInt()?

Comment: Because you always say `intent.putExtra("accountID", data_array[0]);` and `data_array[0] == 0` ?

Comment: @0X0nosugar
no, data_array is always something else, look this line-> String[] data_array = accounts_array[z].split("\\,");        i also use Logcat and it is working fine - look Log.e("accountID",...);

Comment: OK, then maybe because you try to get the extra with a different key (not "accountID", maybe because of a typo)? - Please show how you retrieve the extra value

Comment: @0X0nosugar please look at code, i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass in the account id as a `String` (because *data* is of type `String[]`) but in the `Activity` you try to retrieve it from the extras `Bundle` with `getInt()`.

I set up a small sample app and found the following lines in Logcat:

> 01-21 18:24:02.525 4081-4081/com.example.todolist W/Bundle: Key accountID expected Integer but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value 0 was returned.
>
> 01-21 18:24:02.525 4081-4081/com.example.todolist W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.getInt(BaseBundle.java:801)
>           at android.os.BaseBundle.getInt(BaseBundle.java:783)
>           at com.example.todolist.OtherActivity.onCreate(OtherActivity.java:24)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)

So in cases like this, the app won't crash but you will also not be able to retrieve the correct value.

In order to fix your code, you should use `getString("accountID")`.

Another thing: your `PendingIntent`s all have the same request code (0). Because of this, they will be considered as "the same PendingIntent". You have to use different request codes or all three `Button`s will trigger the same behavior.

Comment: omg thank you, it works! I have wasted so many hours on this silly issue